# Scala: (Int, Int) => Int doesn't match (Int, Int) => Int

Tags: scala, greatest-common-divisor, y-combinator

I'm trying to use the y-combinator to define gcd in scala:

```
object Main {
  def y[A,B]( f : (A => B) => A => B ) : A => B = f(y(f))
  def gcd = y[(Int,Int),Int]( (g) => (x,y) => if (x == 0) y else g(y % x, x) )
}
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Main.scala:3: error: type mismatch;                                                  
 found   : (Int, Int) => Int                                                               
 required: (Int, Int) => Int                                                               
    def gcd = y[(Int,Int),Int]( (g) => (x :Int,y :Int) => if (x == 0) y else g(y % x, x) ) 
                                                       ^
```

If I curry all the arguments, then there's no problem:

```
def gcd = y[Int,Int => Int]( g => x => y => if (x == 0) y else g(y % x)(x) )
```

What am I doing wrong in the uncurried version?

Comment: Something to do with the argument `y` and the `y` combinator you defined?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bit with `(g) => (x :Int,y :Int) =>`. Scala expects your argument to be a tuple of (Int,Int), so it would be more like `(g) => (tup: (Int, Int)) =>`

You can use a bit of pattern matching to avoid having to use `_1` and `_2` matching on tup. This compiles just fine for me:

```
def gcd = y[(Int, Int), Int](g => {
  case (x,y) => if(x == 0) y else g(y % x, x)
})
```

Comment: Great!  That gets it working.  I'd also like to understand what the compiler was complaining about.  Can you help interpret the error? When is a tuple not a tuple?

Comment: @rampion "When is a tuple not a tuple?" sounds like a great question in its own right. The error notation certainly is ambiguous.

Comment: I agree that the error is ambiguous. Maybe I'm missing something, but it would be cool to be able to pass in tuples as argument lists, a la `val x = (1,"hi"); def foo(a:Int, b:String) = ...; foo(x)`

Comment: @DanBurton: Apparently the answer is "when it's a set of arguments."  Looks like the compiler displays "functions that take n arguments" and "functions that take a single n-tuple argument" identically, but treats them differently: https://gist.github.com/1655807

Comment: in case anyone following this, `def y[A,B]( f : (A => B) => A => B ) : A => B = f(y(f))`  should be written as `def y[A,B]( f : (A => B) => A => B ) : A => B = f(y(f))(_:A)` Otherwise, you will get `StackOverflowError`